# Validation Causing Inconsistencies

Tags: php, validation, mysqli

I am trying to code a simple validation exercise for a username, password combination that will validate input and point out to users where their errors are and I am getting a strange outcome that i cannot fathom out why.

If a user has a password called *Password* then the code validates, however if they have a password as *Password1* then I get the response that the username and password combination is incorrect even though I have changed it in the database.

Would anyone have come across this issue before and how could I go about fixing it?

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
         <h1>Log In</h1>
        <form action="login.php" method="post">
            <ul id="login">
                <li> Username: <br />
                    <input type ="text" name="username"/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    Password: <br/>
                    <input type="password" name="password"/>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="submit" value="Log In"/>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="Registration.php">Register</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

<?php


   $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
function user_exists($username){
$server = 'localhost';
$user='root';
$password='';
$db = 'finance_checker';

$mysqli = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $db);

if(mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL".mysqli_connect_error();
}
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `UserName` = '$username'");

return ($res->num_rows>0);
$res->close();
}
function userLogin ($username, $password){
$server = 'localhost';
$user='root';
$pass='';
$db = 'finance_checker';

$mysqli = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $db);
    $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `UserName`='$username' AND `Password` = $password");
    if($res&&$res->num_rows>0){
        return true;;
       }else{

        return false;
    }
}


if(empty($_POST)==false){

    if(empty($username)==true ||empty($password)==true){
        echo "Please complete both sections of the form!<br />";
    } else if(empty($username)==true){
            echo "You must enter a username!<br />";
    } else if(empty ($password)==true){
            echo "You must enter a password!<br />";
    } else if (user_exists($username)==false){
        echo "Username cannot be found. Click on the register link to create a new account.";  
    } else{
    $login = userLogin($username, $password);


    if($login == false){
        echo 'Username and Password combination is not compatible!';

    } else{

        header("Location:home.php ");
        }        
    }
}

?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: SQL injection. Also please remember to add a die; or exit after the header. The header does not ensure that script execution stops.

Comment: SQL injection anyone? Either use [`mysqli::real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or switch to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and use prepared statments!

Comment: Thanks Ronni, I'll add a die or exit.

Comment: PS: Nothing after a `return` statement in PHP will get executed. So in your code: `return ($res->num_rows>0); $res->close();` the second operation does not get executed, **ever**.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing quotes:

```
...`='$username' AND `Password` = $password"
                                 ^--       ^--
```

Without them, you're inserting a bare word into the query, which MySQL will treat as a field name. Given taht 'password` works, remember that

```
Password = password
```

would be valid sql, "where this field is equal to itself".

You want:

```
... AND `Password` = '$password`
```

note the quotes.

You are are also **WIDE** open for [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), so stop working on this code until you've learned about the problem and how to avoid it. Your actual problem stems from this injection vulnerability.

Comment: Stupid mistake, thanks for pointing it out. Thanks also for the link to SQL Injection I realise its something important that I will need to take more care with.